# Welcher, welche, welches als Relativpronomen

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, style, relative-pronoun

Also das ist jetzt vielleicht eine etwas komische Frage, aber ich bin inzwischen wirklich unschlüssig, ob *welcher, welche, welches* als Alternativen zu *der, die, das* komplett richtig sind bzw. stilistisch schön oder unschön sind. Ich dachte bisher, dass beide Formen gleichwertig sind und habe sie alternierend benutzt, um Wortwiederholungen zu vermeiden.

Meine Oma ist der festen Überzeugung, dass diese, wenn überhaupt korrektes Deutsch, stilistisch unschön seien und in einer Abschlussarbeit oder Ähnlichem nichts zu suchen haben.

Was stimmt?

Hier noch ein beispielhafter Vergleich:

> Über die letzten zwei Jahrzehnte haben sich aus simplen Websites
>   komplexe Web-Applikationen entwickelt, welche inzwischen mit
>   traditionellen Desktop-Anwendungen konkurrieren.

vs.

> Über die letzten zwei Jahrzehnte haben sich aus simplen Websites
>   komplexe Web-Applikationen entwickelt, die inzwischen mit
>   traditionellen Desktop-Anwendungen konkurrieren.

**Edit:** Hier eine Quelle, die meine Oma unterstützt: https://www.scribbr.de/akademisches-schreiben/verbotene-woerter-in-einer-abschlussarbeit/

Comment: Ohne Frage korrektes Deutsch. Über Stil lässt sich (nicht) streiten. Ich teile die Auffassung deiner Oma nicht.

Comment: Korrektes Deutsch auf alle Fälle, stilistisch lässt sich das nur für jeden Satz einzeln beurteilen. Im vorliegenden Fall empfinde ich die Variante mit *welche* als geringfügig besser.

Comment: Korrekt? Ja. Ungewöhnlich und auf dem Wege, archaisch zu werden? M.E. ganz eindeutig.

Comment: Never ask your grandma for correct language ... ;D

Comment: Wortwiederholungen zu vermeiden, ist für eine wissenschaftlichen Arbeit kein hinreichender Grund, von bestem Wort/Begriff abzuweichen.

Comment: Korrektes Deutsch: Auf jeden Fall. Vom Stil her würde ich selbst allerdings "der, die das" vorziehen. "Welcher, welche, welches" wirkt heutzutage eher archaisch und "geschraubt" wie bürokratisches Amtsdeutsch. Und "Wortwiederholungen vermeiden" und Artikel/Pronomen wie "der, die das", die in der deutschen Sprache einfach überall vorhanden sein *müssen* und sind, hat mich in dieser Kombination zum Lachen gebracht - Hört sich ein bißchen an wie "ich will französisch schreiben, mag aber keine Akzente - was soll ich tun?". Ich glaube, du überdenkst da was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dass es sich bei beiden Beispielen um korrektes Deutsch handelt, steht [außer Frage](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/welcher_welch_der_dieser_jener).

Was an der Verwendung von *welcher*, *welch*, *welche* und *welches* stilistisch unschön sein sollte, erschließt sich mir nicht. Aber Stilfragen sind nicht selten Geschmacksfragen.

So ist für meinen Geschmack das Duden-Beispiel

> diejenigen, *welche* die beste Arbeit geleistet hatten

stilistisch besser als die Alternative

> diejenigen, *die* die beste Arbeit geleistet hatten.

Die Einschätzung, diese Pronomen hätten *"in einer Abschlussarbeit oder Ähnlichem nichts zu suchen"*, halte ich für nicht nur äußerst fragwürdig, sondern unbegründet und haltlos.

Comment: Was sagst du zu der Quelle im Edit?

Comment: Aus derselben Quelle: Statt *Die Lösung ist einfach.* muss es heißen: *Die Lösung erweist sich als unkompliziert.*? Die Bezeichnung *verbotene Wörter* sagt eigentlich schon alles, was man zur Qualität dieser Quelle wissen muss. ;)

Answer (score 2):

allerdings steht im Duden "Richtiges und gutes Deutsch" unter "welcher": 3. "[...] Das Relativpronomen *welcher, welche, welches* wirkt im Allgemeinen schwerfällig und sollte gemieden werden[.]"

Bei dem Beispiel "diejenigen, die" hätte man eine Wortwiederholung. Die ist stilistisch tatsächlich nicht schön.

Answer (score 1):

Die Beispiele hinter dem Link im Edit sind in der Tat etwas schwerfällig.

Das im Beitrag klingt dagegen "rund"; vermutlich dadurch, dass "welche" sich auf eine ausführliche Beschreibung bezieht.

Duden und scribbr wenden sich wohl an Menschen ohne musikalische Ader. Wenn´s harmonisch klingt, ist es für mich richtig. Das hat bisher immer hingehauen.